# Why my camera matrix is an identity matrix after calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

After calibrating my camera using some sample data in `OpenCV`, my camera matrix becomes an identity matrix.
Here is my code:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> t_3d;
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(50, 100, 0));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(375, 100, 0));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(50, 1600, 0));
t_3d.push_back(cv::Point3f(750, 1600, 0));
object_points.push_back(t_3d);

std::vector<cv::Point2f> t_2d;
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(2.27556, 98.9867));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(631.467, 58.0267));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(207.076, 1020.59));
t_2d.push_back(cv::Point2f(1061.55, 969.387));
image_points.push_back(t_2d);

cv::calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, cv::Size(1440, 900), cam_mat,
                    dist_coeffs, rvecs, tvecs, CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS);
```

Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: what did you initialize your cam_mat to?

Comment: @maditya Nothing, just a simple declaration of `cv::Mat cam_mat;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#double%20calibrateCamera%28InputArrayOfArrays%20objectPoints,%20InputArrayOfArrays%20imagePoints,%20Size%20imageSize,%20InputOutputArray%20cameraMatrix,%20InputOutputArray%20distCoeffs,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20rvecs,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20tvecs,%20int%20flags,%20TermCriteria%20criteria%29), you need to initialize your camera matrix at least partially beforehand.

From the docs:

> If CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS and/or CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO are specified, some or all of fx, fy, cx, cy must be initialized before calling the function.

and

> CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS cameraMatrix contains valid initial values of fx, fy, cx, cy that are optimized further. Otherwise, (cx, cy) is initially set to the image center ( imageSize is used), and focal distances are computed in a least-squares fashion.

In your case, since you haven't set cam_mat to any value, I believe c_x and c_y are being set to the image center (presumably (0,0)) and the focal distances f_x and f_y are 1 because of your use of CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS.

Try passing in 0 instead of that flag.

Comment: `0` instead of `CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS` works.